# url rewriting using .htaccess for unwanted words removal

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to rewrite url where the url is:

```
http://www.domainname.co.uk/blog/gallery/gallery2  --> URL1
```

which need to be

```
http://www.domainname.co.uk/gallery/gallery2   ---> URL2
```

where http://www.domainname.co.uk/blog is a directory with wordpress installed.
Now when i enter URL2 it should show the content of URL1. 
Is it possible? I just need to remove the word blog.

-----------my .htaccess---------

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(gallery/.+)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Consider using the Redirection plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited*:
You can do use the rewrite rule as follows if you are using index.php in root folder where htaccess resides.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(gallery/.+)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^gallery$ http://www.domainname.co.uk/blog/gallery/1$ [L,P]

    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi anil.. Thanks for the reply but its not working :( looks like there's a problem in wordpress with .htaccess?

Comment: what's the problem in wordpress ?? Can you specify so i can help you in detail? The upper htaccess Rule is working with wordpress as well if you test it again ( if you copied my older htaccess codes from above, i edited it with my new htaccess)